# Foundation - Trying to align a search bar and search button next to each other

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

So im working with Foundation and I am trying to align the Search bar and search button next to each other. I've tried putting them into a container, and floating them left and right respectively, but that didn't work.

This is what it looks like now: https://gyazo.com/59a22c3c9cd849b1dd9fec6bb9df6bd5

And this is the HTML:

```
  <div class="top-bar-right">
  <ul class="menu">
  <form method="GET" action="">

  <li><input type="text" align="middle" name="search" value="{{ request.GET.search }}"placeholder="Search by Title"></input></li>
  <li><button type="button input" class="button">Search</button></li>

  </form>

</ul>
</div>
```

but I want them to be side by side.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Forgot to add my html!

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: @MichaelCoker Added the code, forgot to do so when I created the post1

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using **span**  ,
 
**li** is block element, 
So using **span** will help you make your elements inline.

Copy and Save the code below as an Html file, eg - demo.html
and open it on Browser.

Try this -

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="top-bar-right">
            <form method="GET" action="">
                <span>
                    <input type="text" align="middle" name="search" value="{{ request.GET.search }}"placeholder="Search by Title">
                    </input>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <button type="button input" class="button">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note -**
I've removed your **ul** tag , it had a css class "menu" , not sure if your code uses it for something.

Comment: Umm working fine for me, did you copy the entire code I've posted properly?

Answer (score 0):

By default each line item (li) fills the width of its container. To display them side by side, you should use **display: inline-block** on line items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Foundation's [inline-labels-and-buttons](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/forms.html#inline-labels-and-buttons):

```
<div class="top-bar-right">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <form method="GET" action="">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="input-group-field" type="text" name="search" value="{{ request.GET.search }} " placeholder="Search by Title">
          <div class="input-group-button">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/67bephm0/1/)